# loading jade after angular loads and resolves all variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have a simple nodejs based page, wherein on the front end I am using angular and on the back end nodejs. Now when i am loading some data in a controller by $http like this -

```
angular.module('student').controller('StudentDashBoardController', function($rootScope, $scope,$http,$location,mvNotifier) {
    $scope.getUser = function(){
        var url = '/getUser';
        $http({method:'POST',url:url}).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
            if(status==200){
                $rootScope.user = data;
                var date = new Date(data.date);
                $rootScope.user.joinMonth=date.toUTCString().split(' ')[2];
                $rootScope.user.joinYear=date.getYear();
            }
            else
                mvNotifier.error("Some Internal Error ocurred. Please Try Again Later");
        });
    };
    $scope.getUser();
});
```

and then outside the scope of this controller If I am trying to display the user in a jade template like this -

```
li.dropdown.user.user-menu
   a.dropdown-toggle(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown')
   i.glyphicon.glyphicon-user
      span
      | {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
         i.caret
      ul.dropdown-menu
         li.user-header.bg-light-blue
            h3 {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}} &nbsp;
            br
            h5 Member since {{user.joinMonth}}, {{user.joinYear}}
```

Then I see that for a few moments until the call to getUser is completed I see `{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}`

and after the call $http call is over it is back to normal. Is there a way to delay my jade rendering until that getUser call is over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `ng-bind` directive to prevent that "flash"?
Or if it doesnt work, `ng-cloak` directive?

PS. In my opinion, the jade template is compiled before you even get the response, so the problem lies on the angular side of things, it just takes time to execute and replace placeholders with proper data.

Comment: [ngCloak](http://devdocs.io/angular/ng/directive/ngcloak) is the correct answer. However, it sounds like your server is really slow to retrieve the data. I would look into how long it takes to retrieve the data and try to optimize that as well.

Comment: @Vadim is right. I would look into the  server response as well as code execution in this case.